# How to left align dodged bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot bar charts on a time series. I have a separate set of events to demarcate things that happened between the data and thus may influence change. I use a vertical bar to show the times at which these occur. If I don't attempt to adjust the x-axis locations of the data, the events look like they occur in the middle of the data rather than just afterward because the bars are all centered around the data timepoint and the events occur shortly afterward (one month in this case). What I wish to do is to left justify the data bars so that the timepoint at which the data is taken is located to right of the rightmost bar. I've tried `just` and `nudge` position options but these don't seem to work well with bars that are dodged (as opposed to stacked). Also tried `position_dodge()` and `position_dodge2()` options without success. Below is some code to replicate the problem. Note that this example just has a group of two dodged bars, but other plots will have more. Also, with this example the rightmost bar is trimmed from the plot because of the axis limits I set, which would/should not happen if data were left aligned.

```
BarData <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(c('01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2022', '01/01/2022', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023'), "%m/%d/%Y"),
  side = c('L', 'R', 'L', 'R', 'L', 'R'),
  value = c(80, 85, 90, 90, 95, 100)
)

EventData <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(c('01/01/2018', '01/02/2020', '01/02/2022'), "%m/%d/%Y"),
  name = c('First', 'Second', 'Third')
)

datemin = min(BarData$date, EventData$date)
datemax = max(BarData$date, EventData$date)

ggplot(BarData, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=side, col=side)) +
  geom_col(alpha= 0.5, position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = EventData$date, size = 0.75) +
  xlim(c(datemin, datemax))
```

[image: Plot from code above]

In the image above what I would like to do is shift all the data left so that the vertical bars (which will remain in the same place) appear to the right of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this? Just substract 165 x=date: Or whatever number you need:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(BarData, aes(x=date-165, y=value, fill=side, col=side)) +
  geom_col(alpha= 0.5, position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = EventData$date, size = 0.75) +
  xlim(c(datemin, datemax))
```

[image]